Add directive validation in a argument using Apollo GraphQL v4
I'd like to add this directive to a GraphQL Apollo server directive @max(value: Int) on ARGUMENT_DEFINITION.
I tried this, it works but I wonder whether there's a better way to do that without copying the type object as a workaround.
import { getDirective, MapperKind, mapSchema } from '@graphql-tools/utils'
import { GraphQLArgumentConfig, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql/type'
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'


let schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})

schema = maxDirective(schema, 'max')

export function maxDirective(schema: GraphQLSchema, directiveName: string) {
  return mapSchema(schema, {
    [MapperKind.ARGUMENT]: (argumentConfig: GraphQLArgumentConfig, fieldName: string) => {
      const maxDirective = getDirective(schema, argumentConfig, directiveName)?.[0]

      if (maxDirective) {
        // I had to copy the type object, otherwise it applies this directive to all Int types in the server
        const type = {...argumentConfig.type } as GraphQLScalarType
        if (type?.name === 'Int') {
          const maxValue = maxDirective?.['value']
          const parseLiteral = type.parseLiteral
          type.parseLiteral = ast => {
            if (ast.kind === 'IntValue' && parseInt(ast.value) >= maxValue) {
              throw new Error(`Value must be less than or equal to ${maxValue}`)
            }
            return parseLiteral(ast)
          }
          argumentConfig.type = type
        }

        return argumentConfig
      }
    },
  })
}


